# dataset.write() results in ORA-00001 spark java

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

Just trying to figure out whats the best way to handle this situation. I use dataset.write to write into a oracle database and requirement is find if duplicate exists in the table already ( not within dataset  ) and if exists then write those duplicate records in a different table . Has anyone ran into a similar issue ?  The table to which i am writing is a huge one and will be costly if I read the existing data from that to compare against before writing the dataset

savemode used is append . Its a kafka streaming application which streams data continuously every 2 mins .

Comment: Can you provide your statement you are using pls?

Comment: Have u figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no UPSERT mode for I presume you mean DF.write or DS.write.

The question is how often does such a duplicate occur and why? And what is the impact if one slips through every so now and again?  am not inclined to have a duplicate key violation occurring with this scenario.

If the duplicate inserts logically are few and there is suitable time-based ORACLE partitioning that restricts the amount of data to check, you can do that on the DBMS side as a periodic process there.

So, I would not be inclined to check on the SPARK side. It also seems a little counter intuitive to ingesting with KAFKA and bang writing it out asap.

An interesting question as any approach to do something has some issue to contend with - caching, re-reading, etc. on the SPARK side.